# who create an authentification system with crypt()

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, crypt

i use crypt() function for protect password when i create user in database, but when i try to make a authentification system for connect my user, i don't understand how is work.

With this code, this always pass into the if "WRONG ID OR PASSWORD" :

```
<?php

        //connexion to database
        include'connexionBDD.php';


        // Check connection
        if ($bdd->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $bdd->connect_error);
        } 
        echo "Connected successfully (".$bdd->host_info.")";

        $pseudonyme = $_POST['pseudo'];
        $password= $_POST['mdp'];


        //on crypte le mot de passe
        $password= crypt($password);

        $req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT ID_utilisateur FROM utilisateurs 
                              WHERE Pseudonyme = :pseudo AND Mot_de_passe = :mdp');
        $req->execute(array(
            'pseudo' => $pseudonyme,
            'mdp' => $password));

        $result= $req->fetch();




        if(!$result)
        {
           echo "WRONG ID OR PASSWORD"; 
        }
        else
        {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['ID_utilisateur'] = $resultat['ID_utilisateur'];
            $_SESSION['Pseudonyme'] = $pseudonyme;
            $pseudo = $_SESSION['Pseudonyme'];
            echo "<p> You are connected with $pseudo !<p></div>";
        }

          ?>
```

Comment: This is one of the most important security principles of an authentication system: _do not store passwords!_. Even your attempt of encryption does not change the general security issue you create with that. Instead of storing passwords you should store a _hash_ of the passwords. Then, during authentication, you compare that hash to a hash generated from the password specified at runtime. The result is the same, but there is no risk of the passwords getting stolen from your system, since the passwords are not stored at all. Take care to use a good and salted hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

crypt() as of now is not preferred way to store passwords.

Use [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to generate password and [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to compare them.

Example code:

```
$password = "tere";
$cryptPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$verify = password_verify($password, $cryptPassword);
var_dump($verify); // Returns bool(true)
```

Also [crypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) is well documented in PHP Manual, read about that.